# submit a form via Ajax and update a result div

Tags: php, ajax

I was using a self submitting form to process the data but I now need to process it separately so now I need to submit a form, return the results and place it in a div. It seems using `AJAX` is a good way to do this to have the data return to the original page where the form is. I have had a look at alot of examples and I don't really understand how to do it or really how its working.

Say I wanted to send this form data from `index.php` to my process page `twitterprocess.php` what do I need to do and get it to return to display the data processed.

```
<form method="POST" action="twitterprocess.php">
    Hashtag:<input type="text" name="hashtag" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit hashtag!" />
</form>
```

This is what I have been using to display the results.

```
<?php foreach($results as $result) { 
    $tweet_time = strtotime($result->created_at);?>
    <div>
    <div class="tweet"> <?php echo displayTweet($result->text),"\r\n"; ?>
    <div class="user"><?php echo "<strong>Posted </strong>" . date('j/n/y H:i:s ',$tweet_time) ?><strong> By </strong><a rel="nofollow" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $result->from_user ?>"><?php echo $result->from_user ?></a></div>
    </div>
    <br />
<? } ?>
```

I'm new to AJAX but any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*When you use AJAX the output generated on other page is the result for this page.

*Now when you want to post data and retrieve results through the use of AJAX then in form part of your html don't use type="submit" for button, but simply go for type="button".

*action attribute should be left blank as you are going to trigger the action through your AJAX code.

*Well rest all your solution in the code snippet below:

Below is the HTML code along with AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Form Handling Through AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXmlDoc(fname, lname){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("ajaxify").innerHTML =                xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo_ajax3.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("fname=" + fname + "&" + "lname=" + lname);
    }
</script>
</head>

 <body>
<p>
    <span id="ajaxify">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<form  id="frm" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="fn" />
    <input type="text" name="ln" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="loadXmlDoc(fn.value, ln.value)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the PHP code that is used in above code

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
echo "Hello " . $fname . " " . $lname;
?>
```

Comment: thank for the great example. I would vote up but alas my rank is too low

Comment: one question. what is the 200 for? ' if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){'

Comment: 200 means the status is "OK" i.e the AJAX function has got what needed and 4 means the request to the server is finished properly and response from the server is ready to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Assign some id to your submit button, i'd use id="submit" and some id for your text field (i use id="text");

Client-side js:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
   var postData = new Object(); //for complex-form
   postData.hashTag = $("#text").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', //or 'GET' if you need
       contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", //i use json here
       dataType: "json",
       url: "some_url",
       data: JSON.stringify(postData), //or smth like param1=...&param2=... etc... if you don't want json
       success: function (response) {
           //handle response here, do all page updates or show error message due to server-side validation
        },
        error: function () {
            //handle http errors here
        }
    });
  return false; //we don't want browser to do submit
```

});

So, if user has js enabled = your code will do ajax request, otherwise - regular post request will be made;

On a server-side you have to handle ajax and regular submit different to make it work correct in both cases. I'm not good in php so can't do any advise here

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, for example,

```
function doPost(formdata){
    var url="/twitterprocess.php";
    var senddata={'data':formdata};
    $.post(url,senddata,function(receiveddata){
       dosomethingwithreceiveddata(receiveddata);
    }
```

your php will get senddata in JSON form. You can process and send appropriate response. That response can be handled by dosomethingwithreceiveddata.

Comment: do I have to get the form to post to the jquery instead of to the php file

Comment: You need to add the function inside script tag and add onclick event to your button to call the handler function in script.

Comment: `$.ajax({... data: $("my_form_id").serialize() ...})`

Answer (score 0):

I find the Ajax Form plugin a good tool for the job.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#tab4

A basic code example could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // On Document Ready
    var options = {
         target: '#output1', // ID of the DOM elment where you want to show the results
         success: showResponse  
    };

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm'     
    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options); 
});

// the callback function
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText +  
    '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
}
```

All your PHP file have to do is `echo` the `html` (or text) back that you want to show in your DIV after the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jquery try this in pure javascript

```
function SendData(Arg) {
    xmlhttp=null;
    var uri = "/twitterprocess.php";
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(xmlhttp!=null)  {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200) {
                var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                var DateNode=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Date')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var Xml2String;
                if(xmlDoc.xml) {
                    Xml2String = xmlDoc.xml
                } else {
                    Xml2String = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
                }
                document.getElementById("CellData").value=Xml2String;
            } else {
                alert("statusText: " + xmlhttp.statusText + "\nHTTP status code: " + xmlhttp.status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```