# Div response in ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code in HTML AJAX. What I want is to get the echo results from the php script on the same page that the ajax called not generating blank pages. Please check my code below:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="machine" name="machine" class="field" onChange='addaction(this.value)'>
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
<option value="machine1.php">Machine 1</option>
<option value="machine2.php">Machine 2</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Select a file to upload</strong></legend>

    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" size="40" multiple="multiple" />
     <br />
      <p></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="upload" />
       <br />
        <br />
    </form>
    <div id="information"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Uploaded Files</strong></legend>
    <div id="uploaded"></div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addaction(actionvalue){
$("#form1").attr("action",actionvalue);
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

The php script part:

```
set_time_limit(0);
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_size > 10000000) //10mb
        {
            echo "<script>alert('File exceeds file size')</script>";
        }

        if($file_type == "text/plain")
        {
            $i = 0;
             $file = fopen($file_tmp,"r");

             while(($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "\t"))!=FALSE)
             {
                if($i > 0)
                {
                    $data[0] = "";
                    $data[1] = "";
                    $data[3] = "";
                    $data[4] = "";
                    $data[5] = "";

                    unset($data[0],$data[1],$data[3],$data[4],$data[5]);
                     $line[] = $data;
                }
                $i++;
             }
             fclose($file);
             $j = 0;
             foreach($line as $value)
             {
                $newline = explode(" ",$value[6]);
                 $date  = trim($newline[0]);
                  $time = trim($newline[2]);
                   $newtime = date("H:i",strtotime($time));

                 try{
                    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_logs(EmpID, ValidDate, ValidTime)VALUES(:id,:ddate,:time)");
                     $query->bindParam(':id',$value[2]);
                      $query->bindParam(':ddate',$date);
                       $query->bindParam(':time',$time);
                        $query->execute();
                 }
                 catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                     exit;
                 }
                 $j++;
                 echo $j . " row(s) processed.";

                 echo str_repeat(' ',1024 * 64);

                 flush();

                 sleep(0);
             }
        }
        echo "Process completed";
    }
}
```

I tried this code but it seems it doesn't work:

```
$('body').on('click','#upload',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var page = $('#machine option:selected').val();
var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: page,
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function(){
        var myXhr = S.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function (data){
        alert("Data Uploaded: "+data);
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: You can use a jQuery plugin like this one - http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Thank you for the link but what I want is to get php response of the script and put it inside the div just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087305/submit-a-form-via-ajax-and-update-a-result-div.

Comment: where is the php script

Comment: I edited my question and added the php part.

Comment: I tried to edit my code combining the multiple upload ajax code and the one that I have but it redirects me to localhost xampp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution by searching stackoverflow and have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
var formObj = $(this);
var page = $("#machine option:selected").val();

if(window.FormData !== undefined)
{
var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
        $("#uploaded").empty();
        $("#uploaded").append(data);

}
});
e.preventDefault();

}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to post to an other script without reloading the page and show the results on the page?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="machine" name="machine" class="field" onChange='outputResults()'>
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
<option value="1">Machine 1</option>
<option value="2">Machine 2</option>
</select>

<div id="responsecontent">
</div>

... rest of form here ...

<script type="text/javascript">
function outputResults() {
    var machineid = $('#machine').val();

    //optional for some sort of effect:
    $("#responsecontent").empty();
    $("#responsecontent").append('<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><img src="img/loading.gif" /></div>');

    //posting the data to your php script and output the results in the div named 'responsecontent' above:
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "YOUR_PHP_RESPONSE_SCRIPT_HERE.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {machineid:machineid},
            success: function(data) {
                // Do stuff when the AJAX call returns:
                $("#responsecontent").empty();
                $("#responsecontent").append(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that I have two different php script for machine 1 and machine 2 respectively.

Comment: It's also a form which upload multiple files so if you change my code you need to change the ajax to hold multiple files.

Comment: This script won't submit your form, it's called when the selection box changes and only submits the value of the selection box to the script it will then append the results of the script called to that div. But you could edit further to submit the entire form or call an other script based on the selection box value: var url; if(machineid == 1) { url = script1.php; } else { url = script2.php; }